# How to use two prebuilt interdependent shared libraries in cmake in android Application

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, build.gradle

I want to include two shared libraries `liba.so` and `libb.so` into my android application. Where function of `libb.so` is called from function in `liba.so`.

I have a Java class which calls native JNI Function as,

```
 package com.test.myapplication;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static{
      System.loadLibrary(a);
      System.loadLibrary(b);
    }
    public native void testSample();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      testSample();
    }
  }
```

My JNI file is

```
#include"a.h"

extern "C" void JNICALL Java_com_test_myapplication_MainActivity_testSample( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    a_foo();
}
```

a.cpp file which is part of my library liba.so is

```
#include"b.h"
void a_foo()
    {
         /* ..... code .....*/
         b_foo();
         /* ..... code .....*/
    }
```

My b.cpp which is part of libb.so is

```
void b_foo()
    {
         /* ..... code .....*/
    }
```

I want to include liba.so and libb.so as librares and not as source into my application. Both the libraries are built using android-ndk independently.

Comment: "I want to call function `a_foo()` from function `b_foo().`" - But your code instead calls `b_foo` from `a_foo`. Anyway, for use `a_foo` function from `b_foo` one you need to link `b` library (`b.so`) with the `a` (`a.so`). The linking is performed when `b` library is created.

Comment: I have corrected the question. I want to include both liba.so and libb.so as libraries into my application and not as source.

Comment: Have you managed to use a (single) prebuilt library in Android project? If no, then there are several questions on Stack Overflow about that. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202936/how-do-you-link-third-party-library-in-android-cmake-external-build-system. In case of two prebuilt libraries just repeat the same steps for the first and for the second library. Not sure what is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you have the Java/Android part figured out, as it has been many years since I have done any Java or Android (and even back then it was at university level). If you don't, I just read a [short post](https://www.baeldung.com/jni) about JNI that gave me a general idea on what actually needs to happen to get the Java code to work.

You need to build a new library from your JNI source code, and load that from your Java source using the **System.loadLibrary()** call. Let's call that **libjni.so** for now.

In CMake you do this via the following:

```
# jni.c is the file containing the **testSample** function with call to **a_foo()**
add_library(jni SHARED jni.c)
target_link_libraries(jni PRIVATE liba)
```

This will create a **libjni.so** file for you, which will link to **liba.so**. You can load that from your Java file like so:

```java
System.loadLibrary(jni);
```

If **liba.so** is not built from the same CMake project, you need* to import it as a target, using CMake's [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) and [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries). There are plenty of examples online and in CMake **Find** modules. When it was built, it should have already specified its dependency (i.e. if you do `ldd liba.so` it should say that it links to **libb.so**). If it doesn't, and you can't fix this yourself, you can import **libb.so** as another target and append it to the **target_link_library** line above.

This should be enough to get you going with the shared object file you need for your Java/Android code to work, again assuming that the process of putting all the Java/Android bits together in CMake can be/has been achieved.

---

* You can actually use full paths to libraries in **target_link_libraries** calls but this isn't very idiomatic according to "Modern CMake" techniques.

---

**EDIT**

> But how should I link libb to liba

Who builds **liba** and **libb**?

Are they sources of separate projects you maintain? If so, you need to alter your **liba** build system so it links to **libb**. Then rebuild **liba** and your JNI lib and your problem will go away.

If you don't maintain them yourself, you need to:

a) Import **libb.so** the same way **liba.so** is imported (`find_library` followed by `add_library` - links above) and then alter **liba.so**'s target to have the **libb.so** target as a link dependency using [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html)

b) Raise an issue with **liba.so**'s maintainer - if one library uses another, it is the job of the maintainer to fulfil this dependency, not the user.

Comment: I do not have any cyclic depedency in my application. I'm building android Application with JNI built using cmake. In the example given asume that a_foo() is being called from JNI. One condition is that I cannot include sources for a.so or b.so into my Project. They are to be included as libraries to the application.

Comment: OK, I'm getting a more complete picture now but just to confirm:

You have **a_foo()** which is called from both **JNI** and your main application, and then **JNI** is used in your main application? So you are wondering how to achieve this in CMake?

If this is the case then please edit your question to make it clear before I edit my response with the solution. :)

Comment: I have updated the question. with more clear explination and code snippets.

Comment: I have updated my answer too. Hopefully the new explanation will help

Comment: target_link_libraries(jni PRIVATE liba) works for linking liba to jni. But how should I link libb to liba.

Java Line System.loadLibrary(liba); gives a runtime exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "b_foo" referenced by "/data/app/com.test.myapplication-yyA38UEBmsXvaqOY-hm_HQ==/lib/arm64/liba.so"...

Comment: I've updated my original answer to address your latest question. From the link in my first paragraph, please read the short blog post. It makes it obvious that you only need to load the JNI library using the Java interface. Linking of the Java interface and its interdependent libraries needs to be sorted by whatever build system they use.